# How to edit/delete all text on an required field in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

While editing an angular textbox marked as "required", I am unable to delete the 1st letter.
 However if I move my cursor to before the 1st letter, and enter some text and then delete the last letter left earlier, I am able to do my required edit.

Note: No such issue being observed while creating a new record.

Please find the sample code being used.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.xyz.firstName" ng-model-options="modelOptions" required />
```

Used library version: angular: 1.3.15, bootstrap:3.3.2 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you tell what have you written in modelOptions.

Comment: `name = function (name) {
                if (angular.isDefined(name)) {
                    this.name = name;
                }
                return this.name;`
            };

Comment: A jsfiddle might help understand the problem well. Try removing ng-model-options and see if its working.

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behaviour as per [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$validate):

> If the validity changes to invalid, the model will be set to `undefined`, unless `ngModelOptions.allowInvalid` is true.

Since you set your field as `required`, when it becomes empty, it becomes `$invalid`, which in turn sets your model to `undefined`. If you add `allowInvalid: true` to your `ngModelOptions` settings, your model will be allowed to receive the empty string value instead of `undefined`. [Plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/AHEubWm6RbZB8o6VIhoX?p=preview).

Answer (score 2):

As described by [@leonardo-braga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29682922/how-to-edit-delete-all-text-on-an-required-field-in-angularjs/29693570#answer-29699076), this happens because the field becomes invalid upon deletion of the last character and the `$modelValue` set to `undefined` (which tricks your getter/setter into believing it has been called in "getter" mode).

---

A [similar question](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11361) has been answered on GitHub.
Copying here for easier reference:

Using `allowInvalid` will work around the issue, but it is not solving the actual problem.
The actual problem lies in the implementation of the getter/setter function, which treats passing an argument with value `undefined` as passing **no** argument at all (although these are obviously two very distinct cases).

You should use a more "accurate" way of defining whether the function is called as a getter or as a setter (i.e. whether an argument has been passed (even if `undefined`) or not).
E.g.:

```
getterSetterFn: function (newValue) {
  if (arguments.length) {
    _value = newValue;
  }
  return _value;
}
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/CF4O6rzfGWHSjHTQamln?p=preview)**.